# Derivative of the mean-by-mean of a density function?

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, partial-derivative, density-function

I have the following mean equation :
$$a = \frac{\int_{a^r}^\infty xdF(x)}{1-F(a^r)} $$

Well, I do not understand how this can lead to this :

$$ \frac{da}{da^r} =\frac{dF(a^r)}{1-F(a^r)} (a-a^r)  $$

can someone please help?

Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Well, part of the answer is you can't show $ \frac{da}{da^r} =\frac{dF(a^r)}{1-F(a^r)} (a-a^r)  $ because it's clearly false; the LHS is a function while the undmantal  is a differential form or something. Possibly $ \frac{da}{da^r} =\frac{F(a^r)}{1-F(a^r)} (a-a^r)  $holds; if so it should follow from the Fundmantal Theorem of Calculus plus the quotient rule...

Comment: Ok to be clear, I know that $$\frac{da}{da^r} = \frac{dF(a^r)}{1-F(a^r)}(a-a^r) $$, I just did not know how to show it. However, the comment below of Steph answer it perfectly. I guess, I did not ask the question clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the antiderivative $G(x)$ such that $G'(x)=xF'(x)$.
We can thus write
$$
a=
\frac{G(\infty)-G(a_r)}{1-F(a_r)}
$$
Taking the derivative wrt $a_r$ yields
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{da}{da_r}
&=&
\frac{-G'(a_r)[1-F(a_r)]+F'(a_r)[G(\infty)-G(a_r)]}{[1-F(a_r)]^2} \\
&=&
\frac{-a_rF'(a_r)+aF'(a_r)}{1-F(a_r)} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
which is the expected result.

Comment: Perfect, this is clear!